# Funny TTY/Terminal behavior when sudo-ing as a user?

Tags: command-line, vim, tty

I set up an Ubuntu VPS from Digital Ocean recently.

When I log in as root, I'm able to navigate around the terminal properly

When I sudo as any other user, I get some extremely strange terminal behavior

- I can't move my cursor left. It overrwites it with strange control characters, eg. `rvm ^[[D`
- I can't use the up arrow to navigate previous commands. I get something similar - `$ ^[[A^[[A^[[A`
- Vim is absolutely un-usable. Moving in any direction causes a strange combination of inserting the above control characters or "overwriting" existing characters. I can't delete either.
- Tab completion doesn't exist at all. Same output as above.

Since this all works when logged in as `root`, I suspect it's something software related which makes me hopeful it can be fixed.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Hate when this happens... I have no solution tho :(

Comment: Check what shell the user is using `echo $SHELL`.  Certain shells work differently.  BASH shell, or `/bin/bash` allows the arrow keys for movement.  To switch to bash, just type in `bash` at the command prompt.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly! You were right, it was using `/bin/sh`. The followup question would be - how do I get it to always use bash as its shell? Should I put `export SHELL=/bin/bash` in the `~/.profile` file ? It seems strange that `root` defaults to using bash but the created users dont

Comment: The command `sudo usermod -s /bin/bash <username>` should do it.

Comment: I am going to put that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` should be set for the shell for the user for the arrow keys to work.  To find out what shell they are using, type in the following from a terminal window while logged in as the user:

```
echo $SHELL
```

if it is not bash, the following will add the shell variable to the user:

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash <username>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect answer. Also my original mistake for anyone stumbling across this was not creating the user with the proper shell in the first place. `useradd` defaults to `/bin/sh` so I deleted the user and readded it with `useradd -m <user> --shell $SHELL`, although the `usermod` would've been more proper :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want to change the default shell, you should edit the value of the *SHELL* variable in `/etc/default/useradd` to be "*/bin/bash*".  That way, new users should automatically get `/bin/bash` as their shell (unless overridden on the command line).